# How to show ::after content on the same line as an <a> element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Have the following CSS that underlines a URL as desired:

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.underline:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.underline:hover:after {
  width: 80%;
  background: orange;
}
```

On my page, some URLs are intra-page links, and the above works fine.

Other URLs are external links and, when selected, leave the page.

To signal the user that selecting the link will leave the page, I want to put a symbol after an anchor statement.

For example `<a href="https://https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>`

So, have created an additional statement for URLs that are external links and include target="_blank"

```css
a[target="_blank"]::after {
  content: "\279A";
}
```

But in that implementation, the symbol "\279A" appears on a new line, which is not what I want.

The follow fails:

```css
a[target="_blank"]::after {
  content: "\279A";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

My question is: for a statement that looks like this:

```
<a class="underline" href="https://https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
```

how to modify the CSS to remove the resulting line-break and keep the leave-page symbol adjacent to the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate selectors that apply styles to the same `::after` pseudo-element. Both `a[target="_blank"]::after` and `.underline:after` are targeting the same thing. You can remove the positioning properties from `.underline:after` and the icon will be inline, or you can move the first styles to `::before`:

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.underline::before { /* I changed this to ::before from :after */
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.underline:hover::before {
  width: 80%;
  background: orange;
}

a[target="_blank"]::after {
  content: "\279A";
}
```

```html
<a class="underline" href="https://https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
```

Comment: the transition has stopped (i added back from my original but it is no longer animated). Would you update your answer to incorporate that original feature? (unless i'm missing something)

Comment: @JayGray Sorry, I forgot I removed as part of reducing the code to a [mcve]. One sec. Edit: OK, it's back in now.

Comment: would you check your answer one more time for me please? In my question, the underline changes color and width. But I'm not getting that in your answer. I tried the inline `Run code snippet` and also copied your answer to my target code - same result.

Comment: @JayGray Sorry, forgot to update the second `::after` to `::before` to match the pre-transitioned CSS. Run the snippet now and check

Comment: OK, i see that it does work correctly in `Run code snippet` but i'm getting a new line in my source code. Have tested in both Chrome and Mozilla. Gimme a sec to make sure I have not done something stupid on my side.